# Can SignalR help this scenario - detecting schedule completion without polling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

On my web page (written on asp.net mvc3), user can create a schedule in ms sql database, then user needs to be informed the schedule completion along with some data as a result of it.

To detect the schedule completion (its unique id would disappear from table on completion), currently I am doing ajax polling, then additional ajax call to fetch result data from database.

Can this scenario be improved by using SignalR and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this scenario be improved by using SignalR and if so, how?

Definitely it can be improved. Currently i am assuming you are doing Ajax polling without knowing when it really needs to refresh the page to display the updates of the schedule completion. With SignalR implementation you will have a server side hub created with hub methods and client side callbacks to handle callback from server hubs. You don't need your client to poll the server to see if there is any updates. But some how you need to have a polling mechanism internally in your server (probably a BG worker) to detect the schedule completion(Assuming this is an automated activity). Signalr doesn't do these automatically you need to have the call initiated from the server to the client hub subscription.

Just as a simple prototype for your scenario, you may create a Hub on your server say just for ex:-

`ScheduleHub` which may have 2 functions say `CreateSchedule` and `SetScheduleCompletion` . 
provided setScheduleCompletion knows

On your client side javascript you will get the hubConnection instance

```
 var scheduleCheckHub= $.connection.scheduleHub;
//when the use
    $("#createSchedule").click(function () {
                    scheduleCheckHub.server.createSchedule(somedata);
                });
```

client side hub method callback to handle the callback from the server.

```
scheduleCheckHub.client.updateScheduleStatus = function (data) {
              //do something
            };
```

You will have the connection start stop, reconnecting logic etc

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
              //do something
            });
       .....
```

In your server Hub SetScheduleCompletion method

```
    public void SetScheduleCompletion()
   {
 .....
//some code that knows when the schedule has been completed.
//Now i know that this schedule has been completed so
//push this to all the clients, ok then make the call back to the client hub proxy method
      Clients.All.updateScheduleStatus(responseObject); 
//No i just want to send this to only specific clients. Ok then do this
   var subscribers = Clients.Group(someIdentifierToGetGroups);
   subscribers.updateScheduleStatus(responseObject);
}
```

Again things can change depending upon the complexity of the application. This is a very simple scenario and implementation.

Comment: thanks for your time and example, sometime I will dig into this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use SignalR the structure of your application would slightly change.

For instance, instead of ajax polling on the client you'd have your server either poll or get updated in some fashion on completed schedules.

Once SignalR knows that a schedule is completed it can then push data down to your client(s) with the information regarding the schedule completion.

Comment: @Taylor thanks for the confirmation. I have been always uncomfortable about polling and this would be an exciting chance to make it better! Maybe server can use sqldependency to get notified on schedule completion, fetch data, push data to client. Not sure server can pin point which client to get the data instead of broadcast though.